# Android Studio : Cannot find the symbol variable error

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to develop a very basic android application. Although I went with the right assignment and declaration I am still getting the error. I have tried different solutions like Invalidating the cache and restarting but none of them worked out.

Splitting into declaration and assignment is already done which in fact auto suggested by the compiler. If there are any other alternative solutions let me know. I have also done re-building my project, but then that did not work as well.

```
package com.example.javadesignapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu ;
import android.view.Menu ;
import android.view.MenuItem ;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout ;
import android.widget.Button ;
import android.graphics.Color ;
import android.widget.EditText ;
import android.content.res.Resources ;
import android.util.TypedValue ;
import android.widget.TextView ;
import android.view.View ;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        RelativeLayout ahsansLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ahsansLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


        Button redButton = new Button(this);
        redButton.setText(" !! Login now !! ");
        redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);





        redButton.setId(1);
        Button ahsansbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ahsansbutton);


        //Username input

        EditText username = new EditText(this);
        username.setId(2) ;





    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT


    );





    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams usernameDetails  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT


    );



    // Give rules to position widgets

    usernameDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, redButton.getId()) ;
    usernameDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    usernameDetails.setMargins(0,0,0,50);





    buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) ;
    buttonDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL) ;



    Resources r = getResources() ;
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,200,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
            );



    username.setWidth(px);





    ahsansLayout.addView(redButton,buttonDetails);
    ahsansLayout.addView(username, usernameDetails);



    setContentView(ahsansLayout);




}
```

}

Comment: Button ahsansbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ahsansbutton) ;  This is where I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace   `setContentView(ahsansLayout);` to

```
 setContentView(R.layout.ahsansLayout)
```

P/S : If you want to assign an id to button, you need to create a custom layout and inflate it to `MainActivity`. Don't forget to assign `ahsansbutton` id  to your `Button` in `ahsansLayout.xml`.

Comment: I am setting my own layout in MainActivity.java through         setContentView(ahsansLayout);  which you can see towards the end of the code

Comment: You can't assign an id to ahsansbutton button because the id is not existing.

Comment: Yeah sure , let me try that way !

Comment: The compiler is now suggesting me to create a new layout resource file named ahsanslayout.xml with an error in the output as "cannot resolve the symbol ''.

Comment: Yes.If you want to assign an id to button, you need to have an custom layout.

Comment: Oh Okay, got it . By the way what qualifier do I mention while creating the resource file ?

Comment: You can have a look on https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Create-An-Android-App-With-Android-Studio/. It will teaching you how to use the `setContentView`.

Comment: Make sure you assign this id `ahsansbutton` to your button in `ahsansLayout.xml`